# C# WebBrowser anchoring

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am working on a browser using Visual Studio 2013 C# Windows Forms Application. I want to have 2 WebBrowser Object opened in the same time, in the same application, however if I try to anchor them they look like so:
 [image]

The first one is anchored to left top bottom and the second one is right top bottom, if I anchor them on the other side too to cover the rest of the screen one WebBrowser goes above the other one so only one is visible now and fullscreen however I would like to have them together each one covering the other half of the screen.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What about Docking the first web browser Left, adding a splitter docked left and docking the second web browser to Fill? this can allow your users to enlarge or reduce the width of one of the two if needed. If you don't need it Just use the dock Left for one of the browser and the dock fill for the other, unfortunately you can't make them grow to mantain the same width automatically but you can use the resize end event to programmatically set the width of the left control to keep them the same size.

Comment: Thanks alot ! Now it's looking nice.

Comment: @Sabrina_cs a much better approach would be using a `TableLayoutPanel` control having two columns which width of them set to 50%.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple approach would be using a `TableLayoutPanel` control having two columns which width of them set to `50%`. Then it's enough to put each `WebBrowser` control in a cell and set `Dock` property of browsers to `Fill`. This way each browser will occupy half of the form in any size. Also the `Dock` property of table layout panel should be set to fill the form.

For more information about `TableLayoutPanel`:

- [TableLayoutPanel Control Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx(v=vs.110).aspx)